# pandas groupby where you get the max of one column and the min of another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
user    num1    num2
a       1       1
a       2       2
a       3       3
b       4       4
b       5       5
```

I want a dataframe which has the minimum from num1 for each user, and the maximum of num2 for each user.

The output should be like:

```
user    num1    num2
a       1       3
b       4       5
```

I know that if I wanted the max of both columns I could just do:

```
a.groupby('user')['num1', 'num2'].max()
```

Is there some equivalent without having to do something like:

```
series_1 = a.groupby('user')['num1'].min() 
series_2 = a.groupby('user')['num2'].max()

# converting from series to df so I can do a join on user
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([series_1]).transpose(), index=series_1.index, columns=['num1']) 
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([series_2]).transpose(), index=series_2.index, columns=['num2'])

df_1.join(df_2)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) by `dict`, so then is necessary order columns by `subset` or [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html). Last add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert `index` to `column` if necessary.

```
df = a.groupby('user').agg({'num1':'min', 'num2':'max'})[['num1','num2']].reset_index()
print (df)
  user  num1  num2
0    a     1     3
1    b     4     5
```

What is same as:

```
df = a.groupby('user').agg({'num1':'min', 'num2':'max'})
                      .reindex_axis(['num1','num2'], axis=1)
                      .reset_index()
print (df)
  user  num1  num2
0    a     1     3
1    b     4     5
```

Comment: I think `a.groupby('user').agg({'num1': min, 'num2': max}).reset_index()` is enough (without the `[['num1', 'num2']]`), as `.agg()` should already filter by the specified columns in the dictionary.

Comment: @Peque - You are right, I test it with `df = df.groupby('user').agg({'num2':'min', 'num1':'max'}).reset_index()`

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to @jezrael's answer if anyone wants to get the first and last values for specific columns, it can be done in the same way as:

`df.groupby(['user']).agg({'num1':'min', 'num2':'max', 'num3':'first', 'num4':'last', 'num5':'sum'})`