# What is the correct syntax for groupby max min

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, max, min

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383175/19267166) however, I am unable to get the correct syntax for my purpose

```
df.head()
            country             league   Win   DNB  O 1.5  U 4.5
113         Iceland  Urvalsdeild Women  3.19  3.43   4.89   2.10
135         Belgium     Jupiler League  1.99  1.99   3.59   2.40
165          Brazil            Serie D  1.71  1.98   3.80   1.90
238  Czech Republic         U19 League  2.90  2.90   4.70   2.25
244           China         Jia League  2.42  0.94   4.80   2.00
```

I want for `country`, `league`  `max of ('Win', 'DNB', 'O 1.5')`, `min of ('U 4.5')`

I am trying

```
df= df.groupby('country', 'league).agg({'Win':'max', 'DNB':'max', 'O 1.5':'max', 'U 4.5': 'min'})[['Win', 'DNB', 'O 1.5', 'U 4.5']].reset_index()
```

However I am getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: I don't know if the rest is correct, but your `groupby` is wrong. You need to change it to: `df.groupby(['country', 'league']).agg(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is because there a missing quotation mark (`'`) after `'league`. However, if you fix that issue, you'll get another error:

```
ValueError: No axis named league for object type DataFrame
```

The error is because passing `df.groupby('country', 'league')` is equivalent to `df.groupby(by='country', axis='league')` (the first case is passing positional arguments and the second case is passing keyword arguments).

Your question indicates that you want to use both country and league as grouper, so indicate it as such using square brackets (`[]`).

FYI, `groupby` also has `as_index` argument that is `True` by default. If you're going to `reset_index` later, pass `as_index` as `False` from the beginning so you don't need to `reset_index`.

Also, `groupby.agg(...)` outputs a dataframe whose columns are only those passed to `agg`, so no need to index them again like `[[...]]`.

The final code:

```py
df.groupby(['country', 'league'], as_index=False).agg({'Win':'max', 'DNB':'max', 'O 1.5':'max', 'U 4.5': 'min'})
```