# Using Pandas, find a Column's value when Group By on another Column has a Max Value of yet another column. Also in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Similar to [pandas groupby where you get the max of one column and the min of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383136/pandas-groupby-where-you-get-the-max-of-one-column-and-the-min-of-another-column)
Given that the Data Frame is about Car Race, we have in df the following [Race_Event_ID, Car_ID, Driver_ID, AvgSpeed]
Group By `df.group_by(['Race_Event_ID'])['Speed'].agg(['max','mean',.....]` can give Group by Stats.
But I need to have the  `'Speed' , Car_ID, Driver_ID` **of the Topper**, or Whose `speed = 'Max Speed'`, and  Similarly the Tailer's Speed,  Car_ID, Driver_ID , ie Speed = Min Speed.

Given that there could be Tie with Top Speed, Lets get Both or at least one.

One Solution is ,

```
df_max =df.group_by(['Race_Event_ID'])['Speed'].agg(['max'])

df_max.merge(df,on='Race_Event_ID')
```

This solution may take time. And within the same iteration of the data , things may be achievable if we were to iterate ourselves. Do we have an efficient way in Pandas ?
And I would be curious to see a Spark DataFrame solution as well.

Comment: Do you just need topper and tailer?  like topper:  `df.loc[df.groupby('Race_Event_ID').Speed.idxmax()]`?  if not, please add your sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using merge, you can try Windows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import max as spark_max, min as spark_min
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


window = Window.partitionBy('Race_Event_ID')


df = df.withColumn('Max_Speed', spark_max('Speed').over(window))
df = df.withColumn('Min_Speed', spark_min('Speed').over(window))


topper = df.filter(df['Speed'] == df['Max_Speed'])
tailer = df.filter(df['Speed'] == df['Min_Speed'])


topper_info = topper.select('Race_Event_ID', 'Car_ID', 'Driver_ID', 'Speed')
tailer_info = tailer.select('Race_Event_ID', 'Car_ID', 'Driver_ID', 'Speed')
```

Comment: Thanks Omar, Hoever, I may still need to join topper_info and tailer_info to get the final output. The bigger Question is, Does Spark internally iterates on the the same Data multiple times to achieve this  ? Can that be avoided ?